# Unique Query for all types of database [TOP(1) ]

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, db2

```
SELECT TOP(1) NAME,SECTION 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE AGE = 10 
ORBER BY NAME DESC;
```

Based on the above query,please suggest a unique query which run in all type of databases(sqlserver,mssql,DB2..etc) or please suggest me a query which all the database accept Top(1) query.

Comment: It's not possible to do a single query that works (unaltered) in all DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Each has a different syntax.

SQL Server / MS Access Syntax

```
  SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s) FROM table_name;
```

SQL SELECT TOP Equivalent in MySQL and Oracle
MySQL Syntax

```
  SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name LIMIT number;
```

Oracle Syntax

```
  SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE ROWNUM <= number;
```

DB2 syntax:

```
  SELECT column_name, .. FROM table_name FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY;
```

By the way, DB2 also supports Oracle and MySQL syntax, with appropriate configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is correct syntax, but I would try.

```
SELECT s1.NAME, s1.SECTION 
    FROM STUDENT s1 
    left join student s2
        on s1.name < s2.name
    WHERE s1.AGE = 10 
        and s2.age = 10
        and s2.name is null;
```

Nevertheless there is no unified syntax for that. Here you have syntax for major DB's [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp).